# How to fetch rows data and convert it into array using commas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I am fetching data from a column and want to store it in an array and then I want to subtract that value from another array but it is only subtracting first value of array.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include 'include/header.php';
    include 'include/connect.php';

    // fetch student which are already in database of event
    $district = ($_GET['dis']);
    @$admdistrict = $_SESSION['district']; 

    //echo $district;

    $ret_ = array();

    $query="SELECT * FROM student_info where district = '".$admdistrict."' AND user_status = 'approved' ;
    $resultt = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['id'];
            $ret_[] = implode(',',$row['id']);
        }
    }

    print_r($ret_);
```

Only this variable $ret_ is giving first value  other wise all variables and functions below working properly . My student_info table is like

```
id  ! name       ! District
4   ! Rahul      ! Karnal
5   ! Sonu       ! Panipat
6   ! Rohit      ! Jind
```

this $ret variable is giving only 4 as OUTPUT. But i want (4,5,6) must be in commas so that i can subtract it from std_fulllist_array variable below

```
            $query="SELECT * FROM events where id='$district'";
                                $showdata=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                                $user=mysql_fetch_array($showdata);

            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                //print_r ($_POST);
             {
                  @$std_list=implode(',',$_POST['std_list']);
                 $std_fulllist_array = explode(',', $user['std_list']);
            $std_new_array = explode(',', @$std_list);

            $std_delete_array = explode(',', $delete['id']);

                $values = array_diff($std_fulllist_array, $ret_);   
            $values = array_merge($values, $std_new_array);

            // Only keep unique values
            $values = array_unique($values);

            // Sort (maybe?)
            sort($values);

            // Convert to string
            $values = implode(',', $values);
            echo $values;
            // string(15) "1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9"
            var_dump($values);


                    if(empty($std_list))
                    {
                        $error = 1;
                        $get_value = "Please select you event students.";
                    }

                    else
                    {

                    //$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (std_list) VALUES('".$std_list."')") or die(mysql_error());
                    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE events SET std_list= '$values' WHERE id='".$district."' ") or die(mysql_error());
                    //echo "$msg";
                    echo "Students list submitted successfully";
                    }   
            }

             ?>
```

Comment: Please... clean up your code so that at least it's readable...

Comment: how to do this 
??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `group_concat()`.  Your code is a bit hard to follow, but my guess is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM student_info 
WHERE district = '".$admdistrict."' AND user_status = 'approved' ;
```